# Debugging an empty PHP session

Tags: php, mediawiki-extensions, simplesamlphp

I'm attempting to add SAML authentication to a MediaWiki installation using the [SAMLAuth](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSAMLAuth) extension and SimpleSAMLPHP. Authentication works directly from SimpleSAMLPHP (/authenticate.php?as=mywiki) but when I try to log in via the wiki I get "state information lost" from SimpleSAMLPHP.

I'm using built-in PHP state, which causes SimpleSAMLPHP to write a cookie with the state ID and uses `$_SESSION` for storage. When I watch the directory specified by `session.phpsession.savepath`, I can see that a session file of the correct ID is created in both the success and failure cases. In the success case, the session file is populated with serialized session data. However, in the failure case the session file is empty. In a subsequent request, the session obviously fails to load.

The code that writes the session is:

```
public function saveSession(SimpleSAML_Session $session) {
        $_SESSION['SimpleSAMLphp_SESSION'] = serialize($session);
}
```

I can confirm via debug logs that the value of `$session` is populated in both cases.

So my question is: what would cause a session file to get created but be empty, given that I'm writing to `$_SESSION` and that the same code works when called from a different file? Could this be caused by the session not being initialized or closed correctly? Would I expect to see this behavior if output was written before setting `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  You might be having problemss trying to serialize the SimpleSAML_Session object.  I am actually pretty surprised that you as a caller would need to serialize this data yourself (doesn't the object handle that)?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, the code proceeds as if it succeeded. I'm not really serializing anything myself, the code I pasted above is inside of the SimpleSAMLPHP library. I've added some debugging information to it but none of it has been terribly helpful, except to see that the serialized object is in fact there and that `$_SESSION['SimpleSAMLphp_SESSION']` is populated when the function completes.

Comment: Is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSessionsInObjectCache set to true and if so what's your object cache?